# How to strip html from Elasticsearch and search API index?

Tags: search, ajax

I'm also using the search API autocomplete module. When I start typing, the autocomplete shows fields with html code.

What settings do I need to set to get the index to store correctly?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem.
The solution for me came from unchecking the 'Elasticsearch direct link' checkbox in the edit form of the autocomplete tab in the search api index.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it! Is this a drupal setting issue or should i be making further filters on my elastic indexing to strip all html?